External Microphone is not being used but detected by Ubuntu 22.04
(using dual boot)
I can't get my Ubuntu to use the external mic instead of internal one. I have tried every guide/workarounds all around the internet, but nothing worked.
I have tried:

options snd-hda-intel model=xxx
overriding 0x12 pin to use microphone
force reloading alsa and pulseaudio
used the alsamixer, but I don't know what to look for there.

alsamixer output;

pacmd list-sources says it's detected:
* index: 1
    name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 46396 /  71% / -9.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "CA0132 Analog"
        alsa.id = "CA0132 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdd128000 irq 143"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a170"
        device.product.name = "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset -30000 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    active port: <analog-input-mic>

The picture below shows that the volume meter still detects internal mic even if external mic is unplugged.

Here it is plugged in, but it still uses the internal mic.

